# predicting class of perticular image after training CNN using keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, prediction, multiclass-classification

**Training**

```
        import keras  
        import numpy as np  
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt





        from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator  




        datagen= ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,width_shift_range=0.2             
        ,height_shift_range=0.2,zoom_range=0.2,rescale=1./255.)





        type(datagen)




        from keras.models import Sequential  
        from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPool2D,Flatten,Dense,Activation  
        from keras.activations import relu , softmax  
        from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy  
        from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop  

        from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard  




        model=Sequential()  

        model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(150,150,3),activation="relu"))  
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))  

        model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu"))  
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))  

        model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu"))  
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))  


        model.add(Flatten())  

        model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))  
        model.add(Dense(5,activation="softmax"))  





        model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy" , optimizer=SGD(),metrics=["acc"])  




        train_gen=datagen.flow_from_directory("/home/vishu//Desktop/basics/dataset",target_size=    
        (150,150),batch_size=100)  




        tb=TensorBoard(log_dir=".")  




        model_history=model.fit_generator(train_gen,epochs=2)
```

**Prediction**

```
        import cv2  


        CATEGORIES = ['1','2','3','4','5']  

        def prepare(filepath):  
            IMG_SIZE = 150  
            img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  
            return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)   

        prediction =      model.predict_classes([prepare('/home/vishu/Desktop/basics/dataset/d2.jpeg')])  

        print(prediction)
```

after using this it always gives me output 4
how should I predict the correct class of image?
here I am taking input images from folders
I have created 5 folders for 5 classes then how should I predict the class of an image?

Comment: You forgot to do the rescaling (division by 255).

Comment: It is likely that the predicted number `4` indicates the 5th class (5th folder).

Comment: But it is also showing the same output for images in other folders

Comment: @li.SQ Completely wrong, the model was trained with rescaled data, without rescaled test data, you are saturating the neurons and this produces outputs with constant class.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do the rescaling (division by 255) that you are doing in the ImageDataGenerator, this needs to be done with new test data, so you have to do this in your `prepare` function.

Comment: cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)).astype('float32')/255       
                       I have added this in my prepare function but still, it is showu=ng wrong output